# How would I make Apache case insensitive for urls and case sensitive for parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

I've such url

www.mainsite.com/data/True  and www.mainsite.com/data/true

referring to to same url in this case it wont work  if "T" is CAPS , and some times the request will come with parameters
like

```
www.mainsite.com/data/True?Url1=YAA 
www.mainsite.com/data/true?Url1=YAA
```

How i can overcome the case sensitive  issue for the url and not touch the parameters as the parameters is case sensitive  any way to achieve this ?

this not limited to this url i would like to do it for all url under  www.mainsite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[NC]` flag.

> Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a
>   case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters
>   appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.

**Refrences:**

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc

Comment: thats include the parameters passed to the url ? its case sensitive

Comment: As per what I know parameters will remain case sensitive.